# What is the unit of measure for a region's power supply?

Tags: units, power-generation

So, I'm casually perusing an old issue of **Foreign Affairs** magazine and encounter a paragraph concerning the ability of Brazil's electrical power generating plants to supply juice.  Said paragraph reads:

"*Domestic power supply is expected to rise from 539.9 terawatts per hour (TWh) in 2010 to approximately 830 TWh in 2019, by which time power demand...should have attained 712 TWh...*"

The units referred to here, "TWh", seem like the wrong choice to me for two reasons.  First, I believe the unit "TWh" is used to measure energy, not energy rate/consumption.  And, clearly, "TWh" does *not* mean "terrawatts per hour!"

Should the above statement have referred simply to "TW?"

Comment: 539 TW would imply somewhere around half a million large power stations ...not credible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They mean terawatt-hours**.   Terawatts per hour is not a thing, but if it was, it would be TW/h.

By `539.9 TWh in 2010` they mean for the entire year, i.e. 539.9 terawatt-hours/year.  Useful to economists, not useful to engineers.  But we can obtain plain terawatts.

With 365.25 days in a year, hours/year is 24x365.25 or 8766.

To get plain *terawatts*, we need to divide 539.9 terawatt-hours/year by 8766 hours/year...  yielding 0.06159 terawatts, or **61.59 gigawatts**.  This number survives a sanity check; it's a perfectly realistic *average* generation for a country of that size.

Comment: TW/h may not be a thing, but funnily enough, GW/year is. You can measure the production capacity of a solar cell fab line that way - each year, you can produce enough solar cells to generate 1GW. Off topic for the question though.

Answer (score 1):

If you had Googled Brazil electricity statistics, you'd have found (for instance) [this paper](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=30472) which lists the 2016 power output as 560 million kilowatt hours, or 560 terawatt-hours. And the installed power generation base is 137 GW. So, no, TW is not the appropriate unit.